# What is happening when I run `python manage.py test` and on which port the django test server is listening?

Tags: python, django

I wrote a test for for a signup feature. When I do manually, the signup process sends email to the user, but when I do it with test script the email is not sent. So I was wondering what is happening inside?

And what is the port for the test server? Is there any relation for the test server to send mail with it? Can I specify the test server port?

Comment: i think u got me wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`manage.py test` doesn't run a "test server" at all, and nothing is listening on any port.

Testing emails is [fully covered](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#email-services) in the docs - as that page shows, you can do `from django.core import mail` and then check `mail.outbox`.

Comment: that was great :D